# How to use trigger to insert a new row in same table (Oracle PL/SQL 10G)?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle10g

My table structure is like this:

```
ID   NAME   DESG     START_DT     END_DT      CURRENT_FLAG
101  John   Trainee  01-Jan-2016  01-08-2017  Yes
```

Now I want to update this record (change in Designation) & at the same time his old history should be inserted as a new row. Somewhat like this:

```
ID   NAME   DESG       START_DT      END_DT       CURRENT_FLAG
101  John   Trainee    01-01-2016   01-08-2017    No
102  John   Associate  02-08-2016   01-01-2099    Yes
```

I tried using Trigger with following code but this returned me some error.

**CODE**

```
CREATE or REPLACE TRIGGER TRI1
BEFORE UPDATE OF type ON TB818 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN 
INSERT INTO TB818
VALUES 
(:old.id,
 :old.name, 
 :old.desg, 
 :old.start_dt,
 :old.end_dt,
 :old.current_flag);
END;

----------------------------

> Update TB818 Set Desg='G' where ID=1
```

**ERROR:**

```
ORA-04091: table SYSTEM.TB818 is mutating, trigger/function may not see it
ORA-06512: at "SYSTEM.TRI1", line 2
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'SYSTEM.TRI1'
1. Update TB818 Set type='G' where Id=1
```

How can I achieve this ?

Comment: what is type? There isn't a column called type?

Comment: Ohhh... I typed incorrectly. It's Desg='G'

Comment: Try correcting it  and then execute

Comment: Not working.... Same error again :(

Comment: You edited the update statement as well?

Comment: Yes. My new query is like: UPDATE  TB818 SET DESG='G' WHERE ID=1

Comment: Can you edit the question accordingly?

Comment: You havent corrected the trigger. Change type to DESG in trigger also. Update the error also

Comment: In short - you can't do this. Store history records in separate table `TB818_History`. You avoid the mutating table error, and - the most important - your data model will be clear and easy to understand, and you will avoid data corruption when somone will forget to add `AND CURRENT_FLAG ='Yes'` clause to the update query.

Comment: @jophab I corrected this question and  query also ...

Comment: @krokodilko Yeah I am able execute the same query for another table with same schema. If I execute this trigger (only changing the table name as TB818_Backup) this query works fine but my requirement is like  what I described in question. Is there any alternative to do that ?

Comment: Is there an alternative ? Yes - use a compound trigger, there is an [example in the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/triggers.htm#GUID-E1150933-9B5F-4AA3-9F49-C222A1618BE5) how to do it. Another "solution" is to use autonomous trigger, but this is a "hack" rather the solution because it always inserts a row regardless of the main transaction commits or rollback - it is independent of the calling transaction.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to use a separate table for storing history records.
 You avoid the mutating table error, and - the most important - your data model will be clear and easy to understand, and you will avoid data corruption when somone will forget to add `AND CURRENT_FLAG ='Yes'` clause to the update query. 
If you must use the same table, then you can use a compound trigger.
This is an example how it can look like - assumming that ID is identity column or is autogenerated using some sequence + trigger.

---

Sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE TB818(
    ID  NUMBER GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
    NAME  varchar2(10),
    DESG   varchar2(10),  
    START_DT   date,  
    END_DT date,     
    CURRENT_FLAG varchar2(3) DEFAULT 'Yes' check( CURRENT_FLAG IN ('Yes','No')) 
)
;

INSERT INTO TB818(  NAME ,DESG,START_DT,END_DT ) VALUES('John', 'Trainee', sysdate, sysdate+20);
INSERT INTO TB818(  NAME ,DESG,START_DT,END_DT ) VALUES('Mark', 'Associate', sysdate, sysdate+20);

commit;
```

---

A trigger:

```
set define off;
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRI1
FOR UPDATE OF DESG ON TB818 
COMPOUND TRIGGER

   TYPE TB818_ROW_T IS TABLE OF TB818%ROWTYPE;
        TB818_ROWS TB818_ROW_T;
    BEFORE STATEMENT IS
    BEGIN
       TB818_ROWS := TB818_ROW_T();
    END BEFORE STATEMENT;

    BEFORE EACH ROW IS
       TB818_ROW TB818%ROWTYPE;
    BEGIN
       TB818_ROW.NAME := :old.name;
       TB818_ROW.DESG := :old.DESG;
       TB818_ROW.START_DT := :old.START_DT;
       TB818_ROW.END_DT := :old.END_DT;
       TB818_ROWS.EXTEND;
       TB818_ROWS( TB818_ROWS.last ) := TB818_ROW;
    END BEFORE EACH ROW;

    AFTER STATEMENT IS
    BEGIN
       FORALL x IN TB818_ROWS.First .. TB818_ROWS.Last
       INSERT INTO TB818(  NAME ,DESG,START_DT,END_DT, CURRENT_FLAG )
              VALUES( TB818_ROWS( x ).name, TB818_ROWS( x ).desg,
                      TB818_ROWS( x ).start_dt, TB818_ROWS( x ).end_dt,
                      'No'
              );
    END AFTER STATEMENT;
END;
/
```

---

Test cases that show what could be if someone who isn't aware of this "feature" that the history rows are stored in the same table and doesn't know that he **must always append** `AND CURRENT_FLAG ='Yes'` to all the UPDATE queries - after a few hundreds of updates a system becomes slow, then 'out of memory' error will appear, eventually a tablespace will be full and the system will crash.
This is not a fault of this person who issued these updates - this is a bad, not intuitive design that mislead people and makes the system sensitive.

```
SELECT * FROM TB818;

        ID NAME       DESG       START_DT         END_DT           CUR
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------------- ---------------- ---
         1 John       Trainee    2017/09/08 09:21 2017/09/28 09:21 Yes
         2 Mark       Associate  2017/09/08 09:21 2017/09/28 09:21 Yes
```

---

```
UPDATE TB818 SET DESG = 'XXX';
SELECT * FROM TB818;

        ID NAME       DESG       START_DT         END_DT           CUR
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------------- ---------------- ---
         1 John       XXX        2017/09/08 09:21 2017/09/28 09:21 Yes
         2 Mark       XXX        2017/09/08 09:21 2017/09/28 09:21 Yes
         3 John       Trainee    2017/09/08 09:21 2017/09/28 09:21 No 
         4 Mark       Associate  2017/09/08 09:21 2017/09/28 09:21 No
```

---

```
UPDATE TB818 SET DESG = 'ZZZ';
SELECT * FROM TB818;

        ID NAME       DESG       START_DT         END_DT           CUR
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------------- ---------------- ---
         1 John       ZZZ        2017/09/08 09:21 2017/09/28 09:21 Yes
         2 Mark       ZZZ        2017/09/08 09:21 2017/09/28 09:21 Yes
         3 John       ZZZ        2017/09/08 09:21 2017/09/28 09:21 No 
         4 Mark       ZZZ        2017/09/08 09:21 2017/09/28 09:21 No 
         5 John       XXX        2017/09/08 09:21 2017/09/28 09:21 No 
         6 Mark       XXX        2017/09/08 09:21 2017/09/28 09:21 No 
         7 John       Trainee    2017/09/08 09:21 2017/09/28 09:21 No 
         8 Mark       Associate  2017/09/08 09:21 2017/09/28 09:21 No
```

---

```
UPDATE TB818 SET DESG = 'ABCD';
SELECT * FROM TB818;

        ID NAME       DESG       START_DT         END_DT           CUR
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------------- ---------------- ---
         1 John       ABCD       2017/09/08 09:21 2017/09/28 09:21 Yes
         2 Mark       ABCD       2017/09/08 09:21 2017/09/28 09:21 Yes
         3 John       ABCD       2017/09/08 09:21 2017/09/28 09:21 No 
         4 Mark       ABCD       2017/09/08 09:21 2017/09/28 09:21 No 
         5 John       ABCD       2017/09/08 09:21 2017/09/28 09:21 No 
         6 Mark       ABCD       2017/09/08 09:21 2017/09/28 09:21 No 
         7 John       ABCD       2017/09/08 09:21 2017/09/28 09:21 No 
         8 Mark       ABCD       2017/09/08 09:21 2017/09/28 09:21 No 
         9 John       ZZZ        2017/09/08 09:21 2017/09/28 09:21 No 
        10 Mark       ZZZ        2017/09/08 09:21 2017/09/28 09:21 No 
        11 John       ZZZ        2017/09/08 09:21 2017/09/28 09:21 No 
        12 Mark       ZZZ        2017/09/08 09:21 2017/09/28 09:21 No 
        13 John       XXX        2017/09/08 09:21 2017/09/28 09:21 No 
        14 Mark       XXX        2017/09/08 09:21 2017/09/28 09:21 No 
        15 John       Trainee    2017/09/08 09:21 2017/09/28 09:21 No 
        16 Mark       Associate  2017/09/08 09:21 2017/09/28 09:21 No
```

---

```
UPDATE TB818 SET DESG = 'QWERTY';
SELECT count(*) FROM TB818;
  COUNT(*)
----------
        32


UPDATE TB818 SET DESG = 'wwww';
SELECT count(*) FROM TB818;

  COUNT(*)
----------
        64
```